# R - Check different matrices with a possible lag

Tags: r, loops, matrix, lag

This issue is quite tricky to explain but I am sure some of you already faced it.

So I have two matrix. 
Matrix 1 (**mat 1**) and
Matrix 2 (**mat 2**)

What I want to do is to record in a third matrix (**mat3**) the value of **mat2**, after checking for matrix 1, but with a LAG. Let me explain.

After the value **1** in matrix 1, I want to check if matrix 2 as a **1** too but within the range of a certain LAG, for example, 1 or 2 episodes after (column).

For example, row number 4 has a **1** in matrix 1 at the 6th column. 
So I want to check if in matrix 2 for row number 4 it has a **1** directly after or after 2 or 3 more columns.

Do you understand the idea ?

```
mat1 = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1), .Dim = c(10L, 21L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("wit5.020", 
"wit5.021", "wit5.022", "wit5.023", "wit5.024", "wit5.025", "wit5.026", 
"wit5.027", "wit5.028", "wit5.029", "wit5.030", "wit5.031", "wit5.032", 
"wit5.033", "wit5.034", "wit5.035", "wit5.036", "wit5.037", "wit5.038", 
"wit5.039", "wit5.040")))

mat2 = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 1), .Dim = c(10L, 21L))
```

So mat3 - where I want to store the result of the check

```
mat3 = matrix(0, nrow = nrow(mat1), ncol = ncol(mat1))
```

So here is an example of a possible loop 
in order to check the LAG - this *loop doesn't work* but it could give you an idea maybe of the solution. 
I am not sure where to introduce the lag. I thought maybe in the *i*, but I am not sure.

```
for(j in 1:ncol(mat1)){
  for(i in 1:nrow(mat1)){

    if( mat1[i,j] == 1 & mat2[i,j] == 1 | mat2[i+1,j] == 1 | mat2[i+2,j] == 1) # lag here 
    {mat[i,j] <- 1}  

else
{mat[i,j] <- 0}  

  }
}
```

Any ideas are very welcome.

Comment: What's `mat1.wake` and `mat`? t should be `mat1` and `mat3` respectively. Also, why are you lagging on rows (`i`) if per your description you want to lag on columns (`j`)? If you only followed your own explanations I'm sure you could make this loop to work.

Comment: @DavidArenburg sorry *mat1.wake* is *mat1* ! my fault

Comment: Either way, you could try vectorise as follows, but I don't like this method too much `indx <- mat1 == 1L ; mat3[indx] <- (mat2[indx] == 1L) |(cbind(mat2[, -1L], FALSE)[indx] == 1L) |(cbind(mat2[, -(1L:2L)], FALSE, FALSE)[indx] == 1L)`

Comment: @DavidArenburg - yes it is on the *j* that I have to lag - you're right. I realise what I actually want is more complicate. I need to figure it out more clearly. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidArenburg - So what I need exactly is to store **1** in `mat3` not at `mat[i,j]` but simply in every column before. So when the loop finds a **1** in matrix 1 (with a lag) then put **1** in every column before in matrix 3. Any clue ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple way to do it:

```
lag <- 3  # or whatever lag you want
nr <- nrow(mat1)
nc <- ncol(mat1)

mat3 <- matrix(0, ncol=nc, nrow=nr)
for (r in 1:nr) {
  for (c in 1:nc) {
    if (mat1[r,c] == 1 && any(mat2[r,c:min(c+lag,nc)] == 1))
      mat3[r,c] <- 1
  }
}
```

Note the use of `mat2[r,c:min(c+lag,nc)]`.  This selects all elements from current column `c` up through column `c + lag`, but it makes sure not to go past `nc` (the total number of columns).  That is, this code is used to avoid an out-of-bounds error.

There's probably a faster, more vectory way of doing this, but the above code should work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your loop. It's really nice. I realise what I need exactly is to store in matrix 3 - `mat3[r,c]` not **1** at `[r,c]`, but actually everywhere before. You see what I mean ? Like everytime there is a **1** after a certain lag for mat1 (as your loop does it correctly) - then actually put **1** in every column *before*. Could you help me do that ? thanks